# por que me salen estos errores php

Tags: php

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Homocerveserus/functions/checkout.php on line 14

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Homocerveserus/functions/checkout.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Homocerveserus/functions/checkout.php on line 14

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Homocerveserus/functions/checkout.php on line 16
```

esto despues de usar esto en un bucle

```
if(isset($_GET['a'])){

                        unset($_SESSION['producto'][$_GET['a']]);
                        $_SESSION["producto"] = array_values($_SESSION["producto"]);

                        unset($_SESSION['cantidad'][$_GET['a']]);

                        $_SESSION["cantidad"] = array_values($_SESSION["cantidad"]);
                }
```

el codigo completo es

```
<?php
session_start();


if (isset($_GET['c'])){
    $_SESSION['cantidad'][$_SESSION['contador']] = $_GET['c'];
}

include '../conexion/server.php';
$suma = 0;
for ($i=0; $i < $_SESSION['contador']; ++$i){
//echo "producto:".$_SESSION['producto'][$i]."-".$_GET['c'][$i]."<br>";

        $query = mysqli_query($conect,'SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE id='.$_SESSION['producto'][$i].'');

        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {


            $cab = $_SESSION['cantidad'][$i+1];
            $total = $fila['Precio']*$cab;
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$fila['Nombre'].'</td>';
                echo'<td></td>';
                echo '<center><td>';
                echo '<center><input type=number name=ja class="las ma" 
                value='.$cab.'></center>';
                echo '</td></center>';
                echo '<td>$'.$fila['Precio'].'</td>';
                echo '<td></td>';
                echo '<td>$'.number_format($total,2).'</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo '<input type=hidden value='.$_SESSION['contador'].' 
                class=jk>';
                echo '<a href=functions/checkout.php?a='.$i.'>Borrar</a>';

                echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';


                    $suma += $total;



        }

        if(isset($_GET['a'])){

                        unset($_SESSION['producto'][$_GET['a']]);
                        $_SESSION["producto"] = array_values($_SESSION["producto"]);

                        unset($_SESSION['cantidad'][$_GET['a']]);

                        $_SESSION["cantidad"] = array_values($_SESSION["cantidad"]);


                    }

    }

echo '<tr><th colspan="5">Total</th><th colspan="2">$'.number_format($suma,2).'</th></tr>';
mysqli_close($conect);




?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Son errores que tienes que arreglar y te indican en que linea y porque es el error.

El primero es un indice fuera del arreglo.

El segundo es una llamada incorrecta a mysqli_fetch_array

y como estas en un ciclo se repiten.

Comment: peor que me recomiendas para arreglar eso proque estoy dandole vueltas y no puedo solucionar se que sone rrores peor como los arreglo

Answer (score 1):

el valor de $_SESSION['contador'] es diferente al numero de elementos de 
$_SESSION['producto'] prueba con la funcion count($_SESSION['producto'])

for ($i=0; $i < count($_SESSION['producto']); ++$i){

el siguente error es por que no validas el resultado de la sentencia debes validar $query antes de usarlo.

if ($query !== false)

luego:

while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

Comment: osea if ($query !== false){while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($query))  o 

 if ($query !== false){}else{ if ($query !== false)}

Comment: La primera opción ya que $query es false si ocurrió un error